# Beacon eddystone background scanning

Tags: android, google-play-services, beacon, eddystone

I have beacon from Kontakt.io.
I try to write Android app that show me a notification every time when I go to the beacon area. App must run on background and wake up my app.

I try to use Google Nearby API but no beacon found. 
Oficial Google sample app also no beacon found.
My own app found beacon but not working on background.
I try switch between Eddystone and iBeacon profil, but it is still the same.
Official app by konkakt.io find beacon.
My own app which list beacons in area also works.
These applications don´t use Google Nearby, but I can write app with background scanning beacons with Google Nearby .
At the beginning I proceeded according to this manual:
https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/get-started#step_1_get_google_play_services

Link to Google sample:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/messages/NearbyBackgroundBeacons

In google sample is BackgroundSubscribeIntentService. In MainActivityFragment I set up all and run the servise. But there is no incoming intent to this service. I have no idea what to do. It occurred to me somehow register a beacon to the application but I don´t know how.

I have Oneplus One and Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 6 and bluetooth 4.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the question?  If you have code that isn't working, you should show the code, explain what you expect to happen and what is happening that is different than what you expect.

Comment: I edit this question and have new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481333/google-nearby-api-background-scan-doesn%C2%B4t-work-after-application-kill @davidgyoung

Answer (score 1):

**You need to understand What is iBeacon and Eddystone**

- If you want to use beacon as a eddystone you need to update the beacon configuration through Kontakt.io web panel ( [Kontak io Web Panel](https://panel.kontakt.io/signin) ) and you have to use Kontakt io Android App ( [Kontakt io Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kontakt.app&hl=en) )  for update the beacon, because beacon will update via Bluetooth.
- If you want use you beacon in Google Nearby Panel then you have configure your beacon as a eddystone. Once you done with all configuration with kontakt io then you need to Work on google Developer beacon Panel [Google Beacon Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/beacons/dashboard/).
- Now you have to setup some setting in Android phone.

  1. Open you Chrome app.
  2. Go to chrome settings.
  3. Click on Privacy.
  4. There is one Item Name as **Physical web** you have turn it on.
- If you are using below 6.0 version Android Phone Then you have to find Google Setting in your phone and turn on Nearby. If you using above 5.0 then go to Phone Setting find google -> NearBy -> and turn on.

Thanks 
I hope this will help you.